Installed the JMeter Root CA certificate, but when trying to run the test script, it is asking to install the certificate again
I installed JMeter and created a Test Script Recorder. When I started the recorder, it showed a message to install the Root CA certificate, which I added to the bin directory. After installing and verifying that the certificate was in the correct place, I clicked the start button again, but it kept asking to install the certificate. I have tried various methods, including uninstalling and reinstalling JMeter, but the issue persists. Is there a known reason why this is happening?
Browser using : Chrome
JMeter Version : 5.6.3
JAVA : 17.0.6
Chrome settings regarding the certificate
When click on start this message is showing

I have tried unstalling and reinstalling JMeter
Tried adding these two codes in the jmeter.properties file

JMeter proxy configuration
`proxy.cert.directory=C:/JMeterTemp
Path to the directory where JMeter will store the proxy certificate
proxy.cert.directory=C:/JMeterTemp
I don't know is this correct or not as I am new to Jmeter.

This message will be basically shown each time when you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder because JMeter doesn't know whether you installed the certificate or not.
If you look into ProxyControlGui source you will see that the dialog is called when the proxy is started
So you just ignore the box, given you've installed certificate into your browser you should be good to go.
Also there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: JMeter Chrome Extension, it's less invasive and you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates
